# another javascript copy question

Tags: javascript

The original json

```
var json = 
  [{ "LABEL":"foo1", "DATA":340020, "BAR":235 },
   { "LABEL":"foo2", "DATA":140084, "BAR":330 },
   { "LABEL":"fooN", "DATA":126489, "BAR":120 }];
```

Below the desired format, where new `DATA` corresponds to old `BAR`

```
  [{ "LABEL":"foo1", "DATA":235 },
   { "LABEL":"foo2", "DATA":330 },
   { "LABEL":"fooN", "DATA":120 }];
```

Comment: Please try to be precise. `jBar.DATA` does not exist.

Comment: More than that, the `jBar.DATA` properties get their values from the `json.BAR` properties.

Comment: @Eric: No, it's a question that doesn't spell out what you're trying to do. It's *very* easy to read this question and not catch the `DATA` vs. `BAR` thing. A sentence saying what your goal is in text is trivial to include, and helps people help you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing particularly fancy. I'd use a nested loop:

```
var index, jBar, obj;

jBar = [];
for (index = 0; index < json.length; ++index) {
    obj = json[index];
    jBar[index] = {LABEL: obj.LABEL, DATA: obj.BAR};
}
```

Key points of the above:

- Using `[]` to create a new, blank array to assign to `jBar`.
- Looping through the `json` array using an old-fashioned index loop (not `for..in`, [that's not what it's for](http://blog.niftysnippets.org/2010/11/myths-and-realities-of-forin.html)).
- Using an object literal (`{...}`) to create the entries to put in `jBar`.
- Adding them to `jBar` by assignment to the next available slot. You could use `jBar.push({...});` instead, but surprisingly, it's slower on several platforms and this is perfectly clear, so...

Comment: *index* can be used instead of *jBar.length*. A decrementing while loop might be faster in some browsers: `var i = json.length; while(i--) {obj=json[i];jBar[i]=...;}`

Comment: @RobG: You must have been looking at an old copy, I changed that almost immediately. :)

Comment: Ah yes! A problem with all this AJAX stuff, pages don't always update properly.

Comment: @RobG: Re the decrementing loop: I tested that a couple of years back, and found it was dramatically *slower* in some browsers (Firefox 3.something IIRC) and not markedly quicker in others. Unlike, say, the equivalent loop in C or C++, where that would be standard practice.

Comment: @RobG: Was curious if those results were still about the same: http://jsperf.com/loop-increment-vs-decrement Chrome is faster with the decrement loop, but I worry about performance more in other browsers. :-) Firefox is indeed slower with the decrement, IE7 (what I have handy) is about the same as a cached-length increment loop. All of which is probably premature optimization anyway. :-)

Comment: @TJ - yes, probably premature. Opera I think was always slow. I just think the code looks neater. ;-)

Comment: @Rob: LOL, fair 'nuff. (And yeah, Opera takes a long longer backward too, worse than Firefox.)

Answer (score 0):

```
var i;
    var json = 
  [{ "LABEL":"foo1", "DATA":340020, "BAR":235 },
   { "LABEL":"foo2", "DATA":140084, "BAR":330 },
   { "LABEL":"fooN", "DATA":126489, "BAR":120 }];

   var jBar =
  [{ "LABEL":"foo1", "DATA":235 },
   { "LABEL":"foo2", "DATA":330 },
   { "LABEL":"fooN", "DATA":120 }];

   for(var i=0;i<json.length;i++)
    jBar[i].DATA=json[i].DATA;
```

and now jbar have the same DATA as the json

Answer (score 0):

you are setting Array property to undefined value. JSON.stringify ignores additional properties of arrays

Comment: I don't see anything in the question setting undefined properties, or using `JSON.stringify` for that matter.

Comment: I don't see question in your question for that matter - "jBar is a copy of json, but how it should be done?"

Comment: @ Andrey: I read that as "How do I create something that looks like `jBar` out of `json`?" And would appear to have read it correctly.